# Dynamic Range In A Formula VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the SUM of the last 5 rows.

This is my code:

Sub SumRange()

```
Dim upperrang As Long
Dim lowerring As Long
Dim testi As Long

lowerring = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
upperrang = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 5

testi = "=SUM(C& upperrang:C& lowerring)"
Range("D20").Value = testi
```

End Sub

The error i'm getting is "type mismatch"

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba

Comment: `Range("ActiveCell")` should just be `ActiveCell`... except, don't use `ActiveCell`, and don't use `Select` either.... more reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 0):

To sum the last 5 entries:

```
Sub Test()

  Dim RngCnt As Long
  Dim I      As Long
  Dim Total  As Long

  RngCnt = Range("List").Count  #List is your Dynamic Range Name
  Total = 0

  For I = RngCnt To RngCnt - 4 Step -1
     Total = Total + Range("List").Cells(I, 1).Value
  Next I

End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: Sub SumRange()

    Dim upperrang As Long
    Dim lowerring As Long
    Dim testi As Long

    
    lowerring = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    upperrang = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 10
    
    testi = "=SUM(C& upperrang:C& lowerring)"
    Range("D20").Value = testi

End Sub